# Article title not linebreaking correctly in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, line-breaking, hyphenation

I have a problem with below title in my bibliography. For some reason it won't linebreak correctly and instead runs into the margins of my document. I have found posts dealing with how to add linebreaks for URLs but nothing about article titles in the bibliography. Does anybody know what I might be able to do here?

Here is a picture of what I get as output:
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\hoffset=-25.4mm \textwidth=170mm \oddsidemargin=20mm
\voffset=-25.4mm \textheight=245mm \topmargin=13.5mm
\headheight=6mm \headsep=6.9mm \footskip=6.9mm
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,sorting=none,backend=biber,isbn=false,date=year,url=false]{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\AtEveryBibitem{
    \iffieldundef{pages}{}{\clearfield{doi}}
}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Debnath2013,
author = {Debnath, Mainak and Dutta, Arpan and Biswas, Surajit and Das, Kalyan Kumar and Lee, Hon Man and V{\'{i}}cha, Jan and Marek, Radek and Marek, Jaromir and Ali, Mahammad},
doi = {10.1016/j.poly.2013.07.013},
file = {:D$\backslash$:/pmj27/Mendeley/Library/Debnath et al. - 2013 - Catalytic oxidation of aromatic hydrocarbons by mono-oxido-alkoxidovanadium(V) complexes of ONNO donor ethylened.pdf:pdf},
issn = {02775387},
journal = {Polyhedron},
keywords = {benzoic acid,ethylenediamine- bis,phenolate,terpenes,toluene},
mendeley-tags = {benzoic acid,terpenes,toluene},
month = {oct},
pages = {189--198},
publisher = {Elsevier Ltd},
title = {{Catalytic oxidation of aromatic hydrocarbons by mono-oxido-alkoxidovanadium(V) complexes of ONNO donor ethylenediamine-bis(phenolate) ligands}},
url = {http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S027753871300538X},
volume = {63},
year = {2013}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}

\cite{Debnath2013}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your minimal document seems to work properly. But you could simply add `\sloppy` before the `\printbibliography` command.

Comment: Does "alkoxido\-vanadium" sort the issue?

Comment: Strange. I have added a screenshot to show the problem.

Comment: I have no problem: the word that has to be hyyphenated is `complexes`.

Comment: @Bernard, if you use `\textwidth=150mm` you'll get something similar to the image included by the OP.

Comment: @gusbrs: I used what the O.P. posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You basically have three possibilities for solving this, since TeX doesn't know how to hyphenate these long chemical names.

1. Add discretionary hyphens `\-` in the appropriate places in the `.bib` entries of problematic titles.
2. Set the bibliography unjustified by putting `\raggedright` before your `\printbibliography` command.

   3. Keep the bibliography justified but put `\sloppy` before your `\printbibliography` command.

I would try (1) or (2) first, and only resort to (3) if you absolutely must have the bibliography justified.

Comment: Adding in hyphens unfortunately makes no difference. `\sloppy` seems to work. Are there any negative consequences in me using `\sloppy`?

Comment: @P-M, I tested your example with the manual hyphenation points added, and it does work. As Alan suggested, you will get better results if you don't have to resort to `\sloppy`.

Comment: For the bibliography, I would really say none at at all. What `\sloppy` does is increase the interword space slightly to try to avoid overfull boxes. For regular text, this might be noticeable but for the bibliography I don't think it's much of an issue.

Comment: Alan, even for unhyphenated words this long?

Comment: @gusbrs Well I would definitely try to add some more discretionary hyphens as well, but personally I wouldn't be too concerned about this. My use of LaTeX has never really been driven by a perfectionist desire for beautiful typography; it has many other independent advantages to me. Heretical, I know :).

Comment: Often using \raggedright in front of the bibliography is better looking than making it \sloppy and have one or two entries looking really bad.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach yes that's true. I'll add that too.